# How to trim (crop) bottom whitespace of a PDF document, in memory

Tags: python, html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I am using `wkhtmltopdf` to render a (Django-templated) HTML document to a single-page PDF file. I would like to either render it immediately with the correct height (which I've failed to do so far) or render it incorrectly and trim it. I'm using Python.

##### Attempt type 1:

- `wkhtmltopdf` render to a very, very long single-page PDF with a lot of extra space using `--page-height`
- Use `pdfCropMargins` to trim: `crop(["-p4", "100", "0", "100", "100", "-a4", "0", "-28", "0", "0", "input.pdf"])`

The PDF is rendered perfectly with 28 units of margin at the bottom, but I had to use the filesystem to execute the `crop` command. It seems that the tool expects an input file and output file, and also creates temporary files midway through. So I can't use it.

##### Attempt type 2:

- `wkhtmltopdf` render to multi-page PDF with default parameters
- Use `PyPDF4` (or `PyPDF2`) to read the file and combine pages into a long, single page

The PDF is rendered fine-ish in most cases, however, sometimes a lot of extra white space can be seen on the bottom if by chance the last PDF page had very little content.

##### Ideal scenario:

The ideal scenario would involve a function that takes HTML and renders it into a single-page PDF with the expected amount of white space at the bottom. I would be happy with rendering the PDF using `wkhtmltopdf`, since it returns bytes, and later processing these bytes to remove any extra white space. But I don't want to involve the file system in this, as instead, I want to perform all operations in memory. Perhaps I can somehow inspect the PDF directly and remove the white space manually, or do some HTML magic to determine the render height before-hand?

##### What am I doing now:

*Note that `pdfkit` is a `wkhtmltopdf` wrapper*

```py
# This is not a valid HTML (includes Django-specific stuff)
template: Template = get_template("some-django-template.html")

# This is now valid HTML
rendered = template.render({
    "foo": "bar",
})

# This first renders PDF from HTML normally (multiple pages)
# Then counts how many pages were created and determines the required single-page height
# Then renders a single-page PDF from HTML using the page height and width arguments
return pdfkit.from_string(rendered, options={
    "page-height": f"{297 * PdfFileReader(BytesIO(pdfkit.from_string(rendered))).getNumPages()}mm",
    "page-width": "210mm"
})
```

It's equivalent to `Attempt type 2`, except I don't use `PyDPF4` here to stitch the pages together, but instead render again with `wkhtmltopdf` using precomputed page height.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I don't really know how PDF-s are built so it's hard for me to imagine what to look for when trying to learn how to crop. Do you reckon it would be possible to instead find the position of the last text element? I think I could then estimate how long the actual content is and re-generate the pdf with the correct length this time. So I wouldn't be editing the PDF itself and therefore avoiding bytes corruption. I know `PyPDF4` has some inspection capabilities, but I haven't found anything useful for this issue.

Comment: Oh but I can generate an A4-paged PDF from HTML at first and I was hoping to inspect the position of the last text element in it. I would then use this position and the number of PDF pages to determine the correct length, with something like 297mm * number of pages + pos_of_last_text_element, and simply generate again using `--page-height`. Of course the mathematical computation itself should be a bit more complex to account for default margins, but it still should be doable as I would know the number of pages in the first PDF.

Comment: Hi OP please elaborate on how you are using wkhtmltopdf without the filesystem? It looks to me like wkhtmltopdf is a command line tool that reads the initial html document from the filesystem and saves the result to the filesystem. If you are able to get the PDF document as bytes stored in a variable in a Python modules, I could show you how to crop it in Python. But I don't know whether that would violate your "no filesystem" requirement because I don't know how you'd get the bytes into Python in the first place without the filesystem.

Comment: Also I think the Python tag should be removed unless you want a Python solution but as K J says, this is a C library. You probably want to add the C tag.

Comment: If you really wanted to get fancy, I guess you could compile the C library using Cython...

Comment: @Neil I want a Python solution, as I am using a Python wrapper of `wkhtmltopdf`. `PyPDF4` and `pdfCropMargins` are also Python libraries. I've updated the question with a sample of how this works. The `from_string` function returns stdout of `pdfkit`'s `to_pdf` function.

Comment: Would detecting the start and end of the text in each image then joining all images together be helpful for you? The text will be flat and can't be copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be better ways to do this, but this at least works.

I'm assuming that you are able to crop the PDF yourself, and all I'm doing here is determining how far down on the last page you still have content. If that assumption is wrong, I could probably figure out how to crop the PDF. Or otherwise, just crop the image (easy in Pillow) and then convert that to PDF?

Also, if you have one big PDF, you might need to figure how how far down on the whole PDF the text ends. I'm just finding out how far down on the *last page* the content ends. But converting from one to the other is like just an easy arithmetic problem.

Tested code:

```
import pdfkit
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
from io import BytesIO

# This library isn't named fitz on pypi,
# obtain this library with `pip install PyMuPDF==1.19.4`
import fitz

# `pip install Pillow==8.3.1`
from PIL import Image

import numpy as np

# However you arrive at valid HTML, it makes no difference to the solution.
rendered = "<html><head></head><body><h3>Hello World</h3><p>hello</p></body></html>"

# This first renders PDF from HTML normally (multiple pages)
# Then counts how many pages were created and determines the required single-page height
# Then renders a single-page PDF from HTML using the page height and width arguments
pdf_bytes = pdfkit.from_string(rendered, options={
    "page-height": f"{297 * PdfFileReader(BytesIO(pdfkit.from_string(rendered))).getNumPages()}mm",
    "page-width": "210mm"
})

# convert the pdf into an image.
pdf = fitz.open(stream=pdf_bytes, filetype="pdf")
last_page = pdf[pdf.pageCount-1]
matrix = fitz.Matrix(1, 1)
image_pixels = last_page.get_pixmap(matrix=matrix, colorspace="GRAY")

image = Image.frombytes("L", [image_pixels.width, image_pixels.height], image_pixels.samples)

#Uncomment if you want to see.
#image.show()

# Now figure out where the end of the text is:

# First binarize. This might not be the most efficient way to do this.
# But it's how I do it.
THRESHOLD = 100
# I wrote this code ages ago and don't remember the details but
# basically, we treat every pixel > 100 as a white pixel, 
# We convert the result to a true/false matrix 
# And then invert that. 
# The upshot is that, at the end, a value of "True" 
# in the matrix will represent a black pixel in that location.
binary_matrix = np.logical_not(image.point( lambda p: 255 if p > THRESHOLD else 0 ).convert("1"))

# Now find last white row, starting at the bottom
row_count, column_count = binary_matrix.shape

last_row = 0
for i, row in enumerate(reversed(binary_matrix)):
    if any(row):
        last_row = i
        break
    else:
        continue 

percentage_from_top = (1 - last_row / row_count) * 100
print(percentage_from_top)

# Now you know where the page ends.
# Go back and crop the PDF accordingly.
```

Comment: Thanks. It's not the ideal solution as it relies on image processing, but it does everything in memory so I'm happy with it.